# TensorFlow FailedPreconditionError when using variables from the tf.metric module

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I tried to add some additional measurements to my training code for a CNN by utilising the functions from the `tf.metrics` submodule, such as `tf.metrics.accuracy(y_labels, y_predicted)` and equivalents for precision or recall. This is done in contrast to most of their tutorials where they suggest the convoluted:

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Whereas my implementation replaces this line with:

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(y_labels, y_predicted)
```

Now, even though I do the `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())` within my `with tf.Session() as sess:` block, I still get the following error when trying to use `tf.metrics.accuracy` function:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value performance/accuracy/count
 [[Node: performance/accuracy/count/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@performance/accuracy/count"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](performance/accuracy/count)]]
```

Most notably, replacing the `accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(y_labels, y_predicted)` line with `accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))` fixes the problem, however, I would like to implement other metrics such as precision, recall, etc. without doing it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Add the following line at the beginning of your session:

```
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

---

The confusion arises from the name of the (as [frankyjuang points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976293/3574081)) deprecated `tf.initialize_all_variables()` function. This function was deprecated in part because it is misnamed: it doesn't actually initialize **all** variables, and instead it only initializes **global** (not **local**) variables.
According to the documentation for the [`tf.metrics.accuracy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) function (emphasis added):

> The `accuracy` function creates two **local** variables, `total` and `count` that are used to compute the frequency with which `predictions` matches `labels`.

Therefore you need to add an explicit initialization step for the local variables, which can be done using [`tf.local_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/local_variables_initializer), as suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

`sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())` is deprecated.

Use `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` instead to resolve your issue.

#### Reference

According to doc of [tf.initialize_all_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables),

> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2017-03-02. Instructions for updating: Use tf.global_variables_initializer instead.

Comment: I tried tf.global_variables_initializer() as well. Thankfully, as mrry pointed out, initialize_all_variables doesn't actually initialize all the variables as I thought would be the case. tf.local_variables_initializer() works fine for this use case.